# "Only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed" error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I need help diagnosing and fixing this error:

```
"Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed"
```

I have the following in my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0" ...

"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0" ...
```

And this and this entry line in my webpack config:

```
entry: ["babel-polyfill", path.resolve(APP_PATH, 'index')],
...
module: {
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      // specify that we will be dealing with React code
      presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }
  }
]}
```

Comment: Looks like the culprit is HtmlWebpackPlugin in my webpack config. If I remove this plugin, I the error goes away.

Comment: try changing entry: ["babel-polyfill", path.resolve(APP_PATH, 'index')] to entry: [path.resolve(APP_PATH, 'index')]

Comment: I am using babel-polyfill, so I need to have it somewhere. I can also add an import somewhere instead, but I get the same error then. If I remove it I get errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.

Answer (score 11):

If the culprit is HtmlWebpackPlugin, you need to add the option `inject: false` when instancing the plugin. Certain configurations without this option causes your built javascript code to be loaded twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! Worked for me too

Answer (score 8):

Idempotent Babel Polyfill can be imported multiple times

Install from NPM

```
npm install --save idempotent-babel-polyfill
```

Then import it

```
import 'idempotent-babel-polyfill';
```

Comment: where should the import be added? In the index/main/app.js or in the webpack-config file?

Comment: You would add it in your project code, so index/main/app.js

Answer (score 3):

`Only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed` usually appears if the order of files being wrapped isn't correct when making use of CommonsChunkPlugin or HtmlWebpackPlugin.

for HtmlWebpackPlugin you can manually sort your files with chunksSortMode

Using `"webpack": "^1.14.0"`:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  ...
  chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
  ...
}),
```

Source: [gdi2290 @ GitHub - 1 Jul. 2016 / 22 Jan. 2018](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/959)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are getting it indirectly from some other babel module.

Possible Solutions:

1. Make all versions of babel modules same.Possibly error is due to different versions of babel-polyfil.
2. Remove babel-polyfil from package.json so it will be used from
   babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.

reference: 
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1019

comment by jameslk

> I figured it out anyway. It looks like babel-runtime has been moved to babel-plugin-transform-runtime and this needs to be added to the list of plugins to use it. Would of helped if that was documented somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you very much for your answer. I have tried a few things and ended up removing HtmlWebpackPlugin from my dependencies. Not an ideal solution, but at least the error is gone. Considering the two solutions you provided: 1. I could only find one babel-polyfill installation in my node-modules, 2. after removing babel-polyfill I still get the same error. I think, the problem is that I had *babel-cli* and *html-webpack-plugin* in my dependencies and I couldn't figure out how to make them co-exist.

Comment: You was right. I tried to look for which library is using the babel-polifill in the "package-lock.json" and updated the third-party library to the latest one then the message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I get rid of the error by removing `require('babel-polyfill');` from the index.js script.